# Arduino Relay not Powering

Tags: arduino

I recently bought this Arduino Relay module (http://www.ebay.com/itm/400757832363?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) and it hasn't been working. I have tested it with batteries, and connecting it directly to the battery does function. However, when I connect to the Arduino Leonardo board, the indicator lights come on for both the In pin and the VCC pin, but the electromagnet does not function and the circuit does not complete. There is no click when connected to Arduino. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not the right place to post about electronics, It appears that your relay only triggers at 12V, Arduino supplies 3.3V and 5V, not enough to trigger your relay.